# Display and format of section and subsection in RTL (Hebrew)

Tags: sectioning, hebrew

I have come across a very peculiar problem. The `sections` and `subsections` show correctly in my output when the language is set to English. But when I change the language to Hebrew which it needs to be to display the RTL language correctly, the `sections` and `subsections` are messed up. I need to understand why this is happening and how to fix it, please.

The only change between the two examples is `\setmainlanguage{english}` changed to `\setmainlanguage{hebrew}`.

An ideal answer would use the `hebrewnumerals` feature, but show only the relevant `subsection` and `section` parts of the number. As in 2 instead of 1.1.2 or rather ב instead of א.א.ב

### Example 1:

[image]

### Example 2:

[image]

### MWE: (compile it in `XeLaTeX` with Cardo font)

```
\documentclass[paper=a5,pagesize=pdftex]{scrbook}
\usepackage[top=2cm,bottom=1.5cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[pagestyles]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[toc]{multitoc}
\usepackage{setspace}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\arabic{subsection}}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Cardo}

% sets the marks to be used (section and subsection)
\setmarks{section}{subsection}

\newlength\howwide

\newcommand\defhowwide{
    \ifnumless{\value{section}}{99}{\ifnumgreater{\value{section}}{8}{\setlength{\howwide}{2.5em}}{\setlength{\howwide}{1.2em}}}{\ifnumgreater{\value{section}}{98}{\setlength{\howwide}{3.5em}}{\setlength{\howwide}{2.5em}}}
}

% sections and subsections formatting
\titleformat{\section}{}{\lettrine{\thesection}}{0em}{}[\vskip-1\baselineskip]
\titleformat{\subsection}[runin]{\small\bfseries}{\thesubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\section}{\howwide}{-1pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing{\subsection}{0pt}{0pt}{1em}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newlength\NumLen
\newlength\LinLen
% indents one line of text. Indentation= width of section number + 1em
\newcommand\IndOne{%
  \setlength\NumLen{\howwide}
  \addtolength\NumLen{0.5em}
  \setlength\LinLen{\dimexpr\textwidth-\NumLen}%\the\NumLen\the\LinLen
  \parshape 2 \NumLen \LinLen 0pt \textwidth}
% indents two lines of text. Indentation= width of section number + 1em
\newcommand\IndTwo{%
  \setlength\NumLen{\howwide}
  \addtolength\NumLen{0.5em}
  \setlength\LinLen{\dimexpr\textwidth-\NumLen}%\the\NumLen\the\LinLen
  \parshape 3 \NumLen \LinLen \NumLen \LinLen 0pt \textwidth}

\usepackage{polyglossia} 
   \setmainlanguage{english} 
   \setotherlanguage{english}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\newlength{\myIndent}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\addtocounter{chapter}{1}

\setcounter{section}{0}
\defhowwide
\section{}
\settowidth{\myIndent}
{\IndOne בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ׃}
\ifdimless{\the\myIndent}
{\textwidth-\howwide+0.75em}
{\IndOne בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ׃ \stepcounter{subsection}
\subsection{} \IndOne וְהָאָרֶץ הָיְתָה תֹהוּ וָבֹהוּ וְחֹשֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵי תְהֹום וְרוּחַ אֱלֹהִים מְרַחֶפֶת עַל־פְּנֵי הַמָּיִם׃}
{\IndTwo בְּרֵאשִׁית בָּרָא אֱלֹהִים אֵת הַשָּׁמַיִם וְאֵת הָאָרֶץ׃ \stepcounter{subsection} \subsection{} וְהָאָרֶץ הָיְתָה תֹהוּ וָבֹהוּ וְחֹשֶׁךְ עַל־פְּנֵי תְהֹום וְרוּחַ אֱלֹהִים מְרַחֶפֶת עַל־פְּנֵי הַמָּיִם׃}
\subsection{} וַיֹּאמֶר אֱלֹהִים יְהִי אֹור וַיְהִי־אֹור׃
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try putting all your command definitions *after* loading `polyglossia` and setting the languages.

Comment: @AlanMunn: Great thanks. It works. If you can put it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is probably that you are defining commands *before* you load `polyglossia`.  Since `polyglossia` loads the `bidi` package when you select an RTL language, and `bidi` does all sorts of modifications to package commands, it's important to do all of your own modifications *after* loading `polyglossia` and setting the language.

In general, this is good practice independent of `polyglossia`: first load packages, then do command (re)definitions.